# Rails installation failed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows, installation, nokogiri

I have installed Ruby on my Windows 10 with version  2.7.1p83.

As suggested by various websites, I used `gem install rails` to install rails. But it is showing:

```
ERROR:  Error installing rails:
The last version of nokogiri (>= 1.6) to support your Ruby & RubyGems was 1.10.9. Try installing it with `gem install nokogiri -v 1.10.9` and then running the current command again
nokogiri requires Ruby version >= 2.3, < 2.7.dev. The current ruby version is 2.7.1.83.
```

Now when I write `gem install nokogiri` it shows

```
ERROR:  Error installing nokogiri:
        The last version of nokogiri (>= 0) to support your Ruby & RubyGems was 1.10.9. Try installing it with `gem install nokogiri -v 1.10.9`
        nokogiri requires Ruby version >= 2.3, < 2.7.dev. The current ruby version is 2.7.1.83.
```

What could be the possible reason and how can I troubleshoot?

Answer (score 0):

use the upcoming release candidate for now: v1.11.0.rc2

```
gem inst nokogiri --pre
```

or in your Gemfile

```
gem 'nokogiri', '>= v1.11.0.rc2'
```

Comment: The issue is discussed here: https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri/issues/1961